# What happened to Muroi in Shiki?

Tags: shiki

As the series progresses,

> Muroi allies with Sunako and her "family". In the final scenes, we see him get on a car with a briefcase containing Sunako.  Did he become one of the "Daywalker" Shiki, or did he just remain a human?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the series,

> he's bitten by Sunako, then becomes the [only surviving day-walker](http://shiki.wikia.com/wiki/Jinrou), and then is seen smuggling Sunako away. Presumably, he'll accompany Sunako either in hiding or to find another village to turn into a Shiki village.